# Proxy requests to nginx from haproxy

Tags: nginx, haproxy

I have haproxy in front of nginx, which simply serves static content.

Direct access via nginx works perfectly fine - e.g., https://my-nginx-domain.com/some-sub-dir/image.jpg. Here's the nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate_key.pem;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @root;
    }
    location @root {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html; # image.jpg is here
    }
}
```

Trying to access the images from haproxy (e.g., https://my-haproxy-domain.com:9999/some-sub-dir/image.jpg) returns a http/404. Here's the haproxy configuration:

```
frontend IMAGES_FE
    bind *:9999 ssl crt certificate.pem
    use_backend IMAGES_BE if { hdr(Host) -i my-haproxy-domain.com:9999 }


backend IMAGES_BE
    mode http
    server my-nginx-server 192.168.1.5  # my-nginx-domain.com ip address
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: From what you've provided, it looks like your nginx server traffic is on port 443, not port 9999 (haproxy will use the same port as the client connected to if unset), and uses ssl.  Can you try changing the nginx server line to: `server my-nginx-server 192.168.1.5:443 ssl verify none`?  Note that it may be better if you don't turn off ssl verifcation (`verify none`), I just added it to help debug the issue.

Comment: Ah, I made a few typos in my comment:
* nginx server line -> haproxy server line
* verifcation -> verification